# How to convert a dictionary with a tuple inside of a nested list?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to create a bigram from a dictionary with a specific condition. Below is the example of the dictionary:

```
dict_example = {'keywords1': ['africa',
  'basic service',
  'class',
  'develop country',
  'disadvantage',
  'economic resource',
  'social protection system']
```

The specific condition is that I want to create a bigram if the words in each element are more than 1. Below is the code that I have been working on so far:

```
keywords_bigram_temp = {}
keywords_bigram = {}
for k, v in dict_example.items():
    keywords_bigram_temp.update({k: [word_tokenize(w) for w in v]})
    for k2, v2 in keywords_bigram_temp.items():
        keywords_bigram.update({k2: [list(nltk.bigrams(v3)) for v3 in v2 if len(v3) > 1]})
```

This code works, but instead of returning a normal tuple within a list (I think this is what bigram normally looked like), it returns a tuple within a nested list. Below is an example of the result:

```
'keywords1': [[('basic', 'service')],
  [('develop', 'country')],
  [('economic', 'resource')],
  [('social', 'protection'),
   ('social', 'system'),
   ('protection', 'system'),
   ('social', 'protection')]}
```

What I need is a normal bigram structure, a tuple within a list like so:

```
'keywords1': [('basic', 'service'),
  ('develop', 'country'),
  ('economic', 'resource'),
  ('social', 'protection'),
  ('protection', 'system')]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks using [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from itertools import combinations
keywords_bigram = {'keywords1': [x for elem in dict_example['keywords1'] if ' ' in elem for x in combinations(elem.split(), 2)]}
```

Output:

```
{'keywords1': [('basic', 'service'), ('develop', 'country'), ('economic', 'resource'), ('social', 'protection'), ('social', 'system'), ('protection', 'system')]}
```

Explanation:

- in the dict comprehension, use `for elem in dict_example['keywords1'] if ' ' in elem` to iterate over all items in the `list` associated with `keywords1` that contain a `' '` character, meaning the words in the element number more than 1
- use the nested loop `for x in combinations(elem.split(), 2)` to include every unique combination of 2 words within the multi-word item

**UPDATE:**

Based on OP's clarification that original question contained an extra entry,  and that what is required is "in a `'a b c d'` context, it will become `('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','d')`", here are three alternative solutions.

Solution #1 using walrus operator `:=` and dict comprehension:

```py
keywords_bigram = {'keywords1': [x for elem in dict_example['keywords1'] if len(words := elem.split()) > 1 for x in zip(words, words[1:])]}
```

Solution #2 using a long-hand for loop:

```py
keywords_bigram = {'keywords1': []}
for elem in dict_example['keywords1']:
    words = elem.split()
    if len(words) > 1:
        keywords_bigram['keywords1'].extend(zip(words, words[1:]))
```

Solution #3 without `zip()`:

```py
keywords_bigram = {'keywords1': []}
for elem in dict_example['keywords1']:
    words = elem.split()
    if len(words) > 1:
        for i in range(len(words) - 1):
            keywords_bigram['keywords1'].append(tuple(words[i:i+2]))
```

All three solutions give identical output:

```
{'keywords1': [('basic', 'service'), ('develop', 'country'), ('economic', 'resource'), ('social', 'protection'), ('protection', 'system')]}
```

Comment: Hi @constantstranger , your code is almost perfect, but for some reason, it creates a new bigram (or in other words, a new 2 consecutive words, side-by-side). For example: `'social protection system'` should be transformed into `('social','protection')` and `('protection','system')`, however, your code returns an additional `('social','system')`. Do you know why?

Comment: This is simply the way `combinations()` works. I selected it because in your original question, you also show `('system', 'social')` as part of the desired output. My answer reverses the order of the words within that tuple, providing `('social','system')` as you point out. Is the desired output specified in your question correct, and if so, is the order of the 2 words within a given bigram important?

Comment: Oh gosh, you are right! It was a mistake on my part. But, yes, the order of the 2 words matters in this context. Do you know any other way to create bigrams based on the order of a string given?

Comment: Please clarify what the order should be. For 3 words such as `'a b c'`, should it be `('a', 'b')`, `('b', 'c')` and `('c', 'a')`? What should the sequence be for 4 words such as `'a b c d'`, or is the largest word count in a given element limited to 3?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your clarification above. For 3 words such `'a b c'`, do you only want `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'c')`?

Comment: It's the latter. Basically, I want to create a bigram with the exact word right next to the first word. So, in a `'a b c d'` context, it will become `('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','d')`.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.